# How are /ɪ/ and /ʌ/ realised in the Nottingham (East Midlands) accent?

Tags: british-english, accent

I've got a sample of a few words pronounced by a Nottingham accent representative: https://youtu.be/2fCSeDEZeVU

My ear is far from perfect and this is why I'd like to ask for your help in this analysis.

To me it seems that /ɪ/ is realised in four different ways (from one was obvious and the remaining three - surprising) and /ʌ/ is realised in at least one expected and one unexpected way.

Precisely:

- ɪ = ɪ (obvious),
- ɪ = i,
- ɪ = eɪ,
- ɪ = ɛ,
- ʌ = ʊ (expected),
- ʌ = ɒ (or something close to /ɒ/. To my Polish ears it sounds close to Spanish "o").

Could you, please, help me understand which of my hypotheses are correct and which aren't?

If it's true that the speaker actually realises /ɪ/ or /ʌ/ in more than one way in these recordings, are there any rules on it or is it the speaker who decides on each?

Comment: Can you indicate which particular words you hear different realisations in? If possible, provide your transcription.

Comment: @StuartF I created a special video where there are the relevant samples. I put the link at the beginning of my post.

Comment: I'm a Northern Brit [born <70 miles from Nottingham so it's not a strange accent to me] though I don't speak phonetics. I honestly can't tell what you're listening for. They all sound 'within acceptable parameters' to me, bearing on mind this is not regular conversational speech.

Comment: You will find a lot of variation in vowels from utterance to utterance.  When you are getting down to analysing the specific articulation of a regional dialect, I feel you have moved from "English learning" to "Linguistic analysis" and so perhaps this question would do better on [linguistics.se]  You don't need to be Henry Higgins to speak English well.